# Feed Me Not importing json data for suggested feed elements in the cms

Tags: plugin-feedme

Ok I've used feedme previously and with success. And I also have a feed currently set up for a simple json file importing news articles. However I am trying to import another feed from the same source which I can see as json if I view it in a browser. The problem is that in the plugin cms it suggests what feed elements I should use (not always all of them). But it doesn't import the data value. So for example when trouble shooting just adding the title it imports title:"" when I can clearly see a title for each node in the json?

I'm beginning to wonder if the json is formatted correctly or it's a problem with feedme's mapping.

As an example I have this suggested mapping in the plugin:

```
Title: <items/DisplayName> eg: Factsheets
```

So it can read the json.

I set the title as a unique identifier and leave the slug field empty so it should be generated from the title.

This produces log entries of:

```
Match existing element with data {"title":""}.
Error: Unable to match an existing element. Have you set a unique identifier for ["title"]? Make sure you are also mapping this in your feed and it has a value. - Element.php: 160
```

This is the same error for each node. The error is obviously due to an empty string being set for the title.

There are clearly DisplayNames set in the json but for some reason nothing is being mapped?
If anyone has any ideas why this isn't working that would be great.

Following is a json snippet:

```
{
    "error":"",
    "status":0,
    "items":
    [
        {
            "DisplayName":"Factsheets",
            "SafeURL":"\/factsheets",
            "SourceFSItemID":"12345xxxx",
            "childviewitem":
            [
                {
                    "DisplayName":"Factsheets",
                    "SafeURL":"\/factsheets\/factsheets",
                    "SourceFSItemID":"12345xxxx",
                    "childviewitem":null
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName":"Business start-up",
                    "SafeURL":"\/factsheets\/business-start-up",
                    "SourceFSItemID":"12345xxxx",
                    "childviewitem":
                    [
                        {
                            "DisplayName":"Business start-up",
                            "SafeURL":"\/factsheets\/business-start-up\/business-start-up",
                            "SourceFSItemID":"12345xxxx",
                            "childviewitem":null
                        },
                        {
                            "DisplayName":"An introduction to the tax system for the self employed",
                            "SafeURL":"\/factsheets\/business-start-up\/an-introduction-to-the-tax-system-for-the-self-employed",
                            "SourceFSItemID":"12345xxxx",
                            "childviewitem":null
                        },
                        {
                            "DisplayName":"Business structures - which should I use?",
                            "SafeURL":"\/factsheets\/business-start-up\/business-structures-which-should-i-use",
                            "SourceFSItemID":"12345xxxx",
                            "childviewitem":null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "DisplayName":"Capital taxes", .....
```

Comment: Am I right in guessing that you are importing in a Structure?

Comment: @Oli yes that's correct.

Comment: @lettie - I run into the same issue. Did you solve this somehow?